# Python: Get last row from Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use some financial functions written in Python which return a Panda Data Frame.

The following function returns a Panda Data Frame:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

data = si.get_data("ENEL.MI", start_date="01/21/2022 8:00", end_date="01/21/2022 16:30",index_as_date=False, interval="1d")
```

Here is what I get if I print **data**:

```
        date   open   high    low  close  adjclose    volume   ticker
0 2022-01-21  6.976  6.993  6.855  6.905     6.905  33639775  ENEL.MI
1 2022-01-21  6.976  6.993  6.855  6.905     6.905  35419140  ENEL.MI
```

I'd like to collect just the last row from the DataFrame (the row with number "1")
So, I've tried with:

```
lastrow = data.tail()
print(lastrow)
```

However I still get the same result (the whole DataFrame is printed).
I'm a bit puzzled. Is there a way to get just the last row?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specifies the number of rows you want to get. So for your case it would be `data.tail(1)` to print only the last row. The default value is to print 5 rows, that's why you see your full dataframe with 2 rows.

Answer (score 6):

With `iloc()` function, we can retrieve a particular value belonging to a row and column using the index values assigned to it.

```
lastrow = data.iloc[-1]
```